# How can I do complex table size calculations?

Tags: area, rectangles

For instance, I want to know:

> What is the most efficient way to present 256 cells in a 16:9 table, giving each cell maximum readability?

In the above scenario, each cell must be sized appropriately to give the greatest possible amount of text information, but the entire table must still be a complete rectangle with a 16:9 aspect ratio. **How would I do such a calculation?** I fear it may include Calculus :s

Comment: Are you allowed to -- if I had 140 cells instead, which are square, can I have 4 cells worth of slack space?

Comment: @DanUznanski the result should preferably be a complete rectangle, but I'm open to alternatives like that

Comment: Also, do you have a desired aspect ratio for the cells?  As is, 256 cells can make a 16x9 box by being 16x9 themselves and just having 16 in each direction.

Comment: @DanUznanski no, just whatever presents the most info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about typesetting on the screen, so we need some restrictions on cell width (or column numbers) to ensure some readability. The most elegant solution is to split $256$ as $16 \times 16$ but you have to check the readability of a cell having width equal to $\frac{1}{16}$ screen width. If readability is too low, see below.
Let maximum number of columns be $m$. Then $n = \lceil\frac{256}{m}\rceil$ would be a number of rows. $m$ should be chosen by you, according to requirements of your problem. For example, if you choose $m = 13$, then $n = 20$. Total number of cells would be $260$.

Comment: Perhaps $\lceil 256/m\rceil$ instead?

Comment: @DanUznanski instead of what? If you're talking about numbers of rows, then $[\frac{256}{m}]$ is not enough. E.g. $m = 11$, $[\frac{256}{m}] = 23$, $11 \times 23$ table contains only $253$ cells, so this table does not match problem requirements.

Comment: Ceiling, instead of flooring and adding 1.  for $m | x$, $[x/m]+1$ gives a blank row.

Comment: @DanUznanski Agree with you here. So that's better just to say "round $256/m$ up".